# Do you know any resources to learn design for a programmer?

Tags: design

Meanwhile I'm waiting for [Design for Hackers](http://www.kadavy.net/blog/posts/d4h-the-book/) do you know any good design resources, as many I love designs by 37signals and I'd like to start making my websites look like that.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you wanting design resources for websites or for general applications. The question "Do you know any resources to learn design for a programmer?" is quite broad. If you boil it down to specifics, you'll hopefully get some specific answers to your needs.

Comment: I gave an example of the kind of books I want to read (Design for Hackers) and the of work I like (37signals work); So I want to read about web-design and web-applications...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm assuming you mean something like user interface design, not e.g. OOP design.)

A must read is Donald Norman's [Design of Everyday Things](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465067107)

If you want a very good overview of how the human visual system works and how this can be used for design, I'd recommend Colin Ware's [Visual Thinking for Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123708966)

Both books are very general. They apply to any kind of user interface (mobil, web, client...). I'd also say that both are timeless. They're not about the current vogue in UI design, but about the general percetual and logical properties any good UI must have.

Answer (score 2):

Do not confuse *usability* design with *aesthetic* design.

While they can meld at points they differ greatly. Your aesthetics can generate visual euphoria  while your usability makes using the product (web site, web application, desktop application, coffee machine, automobile, etc..) a difficult and cumbersome task.

Make sure you understand the differences as they are key to a successful .

A book applicable to usability design is [Don't Make Me Think](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321344758) which I highly recommend.